# Unable to ping scan my machine (but I can ping)

Tags: networking, security, nmap

I need to perform an nmap scan on all of the (responding) IPs in an array of VLANs.

The command is nested in a PowerShell for loop and looks something like this:

`nmap.exe -Pn -T4 -A -oG [FILE].txt -oX [FILE].xml "$($subnet).0/24"`

We had to add the -Pn flag as the command wasn't picking up all of the hosts in each VLAN with a ping scan.

The issue is that we believe the command is taking too long and so we would like to only scan the hosts that respond to the ping scan.

I found one machine that responds to a simple `ping [MACHINE]` however running `nmap -sn [MACHINE]` results in `Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn`

I'm not sure why I am able to ping the machine but nmap isn't? Running nmap in an Administrator PowerShell console does not resolve the issue.

I ran `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow` on the problem machine in order to allow ICMP traffic but this did not work either.

This is driving me crazy. Is anyone able to help me with this?

Thanks,

TheCube

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this to the command to see if it fixes it? --disable-arp-ping

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. This did not resolve the issue unfortunately. There is some good documentation here on alternative host discovery techniques https://nmap.org/book/host-discovery-techniques.html but I didn't have much luck with these either

Comment: I see some things online about the PCs having multiple network adapters having this same issue.  On the computer you are pinging, does it have multiple network adapters?  If so, can you disable all but the primary connection?

Comment: Also, is it possible to temporarily turn off the firewall on the PC you are trying to nmap to see if it is a firewall problem.  I don't know which version of nmap you are running either...do you have the latest version?

Comment: I was unable to replicate the issue again. This resolved itself. Thanks for your help.